# Selectively delete methods in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, methods

In a bean class, suppose there are 100 getters and setters methods. How to quickly remove all the setters from that class?
Is there any shortcut in eclipse to selectively delete large number of methods at one go?

Comment: go to the outline, sort by A-Z, select the setters by using shift key and cursors then press DEL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this from the outline:

- Open the outline
- Order from A to Z
- Select the setters by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> and pressing <kbd>Cursor down</kbd> / <kbd>Page down</kbd>
- Press the <kbd>Del</kbd> key

Should look similar to this (sorry, I didn't have 100 setters at hand ;-))

[image: Outline]

To move the getters out of the way you could open the filters by clicking on the downwards triangle:

[image: Filters]

This will work if you only have getters and setters and no other methods. Unfortunately I found no way of telling the filter "not set*".